# Error "ValueError: Graph disconnected" in Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am getting an error in Tensorflow 2. How can I solve it?

Here is my code (assume all the relevant modules/objects of Keras have been imported):

```
dense1 = 2**7
dense2 = 2**8
dense3 = 2**9
dropout = 0.8
price_loss = 1
cut_loss = 1
activation= LeakyReLU()

#====================================================================

# INPUTS

#====================================================================


#----------------------------------------------------------------

carat = Input(
    shape= (1,),
    batch_size= batch_size,
    name= 'carat'
)

#----------------------------------------------------------------

color = Input(
    shape= (1,),
    batch_size= batch_size,
    name= 'color'
)

#----------------------------------------------------------------

clarity = Input(
    shape= (1,),
    batch_size= batch_size,
    name= 'clarity'
)

#----------------------------------------------------------------

depth = Input(
    shape= (1,),
    batch_size= batch_size,
    name= 'depth'
)

#----------------------------------------------------------------

table = Input(
    shape= (1,),
    batch_size= batch_size,
    name= 'table'
)

#----------------------------------------------------------------

x = Input(
    shape= (1,),
    batch_size= batch_size,
    name= 'x'
)

#----------------------------------------------------------------

y = Input(
    shape= (1,),
    batch_size= batch_size,
    name= 'y'
)

#----------------------------------------------------------------

z = Input(
    shape= (1,),
    batch_size= batch_size,
    name= 'z'
)

#----------------------------------------------------------------

#====================================================================

# CREATE EMBEDDINGS FOR CATEGORICAL FEATURES "COLOR" AND "CLARITY"

#====================================================================


color = Embedding(input_dim = 7, output_dim = 1, name = 'color_emb')(color)

clarity = Embedding(input_dim = 8, output_dim = 1, name = 'clarity_emb')(clarity)

color = Flatten()(color)

clarity = Flatten()(clarity)


#====================================================================

# CONCATENATE FEATURES

#====================================================================


x = Concatenate()([color, clarity, carat, depth, table, x, y, z])


#====================================================================

# DENSE NETWORK

#====================================================================


x = Dense(dense1, activation = activation)(x)

x = BatchNormalization()(x)

x = Dense(dense2, activation = activation)(x)

x = BatchNormalization()(x)

x = Dense(dense3, activation = activation)(x)

x = BatchNormalization()(x)

x = Dropout(dropout)(x)

#====================================================================

# PREDICTIONS

# ====================================================================

cut = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)

price = Dense(1)(x)

#====================================================================

# DEFINE THE MODEL

# ====================================================================

model = Model(inputs = [carat, color, clarity, depth, table, x, y, z] , outputs = [cut , price])

#====================================================================

# COMPILE THE MODEL

# ====================================================================

model.compile(

        optimizer = 'Adam',

        loss = {

            "price": "huber_loss",


            "cut": "binary_crossentropy",


        },

        loss_weights = [price_loss, cut_loss],

        metrics = {

            "price": ["mean_absolute_percentage_error"],


            "cut": [tf.keras.metrics.AUC(), tf.keras.metrics.Precision(thresholds = thresholds)],

        }
    )
```

Stack trace:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Functional inputs must come from `tf.keras.Input` (thus holding past layer metadata), they cannot be the output of a previous non-Input layer. Here, a tensor specified as input to "functional_1" was not an Input tensor, it was generated by layer flatten_8.
Note that input tensors are instantiated via `tensor = tf.keras.Input(shape)`.
The tensor that caused the issue was: flatten_8/Reshape:0
WARNING:tensorflow:Functional inputs must come from `tf.keras.Input` (thus holding past layer metadata), they cannot be the output of a previous non-Input layer. Here, a tensor specified as input to "functional_1" was not an Input tensor, it was generated by layer flatten_9.
Note that input tensors are instantiated via `tensor = tf.keras.Input(shape)`.
The tensor that caused the issue was: flatten_9/Reshape:0
WARNING:tensorflow:Functional inputs must come from `tf.keras.Input` (thus holding past layer metadata), they cannot be the output of a previous non-Input layer. Here, a tensor specified as input to "functional_1" was not an Input tensor, it was generated by layer dropout_2.
Note that input tensors are instantiated via `tensor = tf.keras.Input(shape)`.
The tensor that caused the issue was: dropout_2/cond/Identity:0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-132a2d8458b9> in <module>
    135 # ====================================================================
    136 
--> 137 model = Model(inputs = [carat, color, clarity, depth, table, x, y, z] , outputs = [cut , price])
    138 
    139 #====================================================================

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    240       # Functional model
    241       from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import functional  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
--> 242       return functional.Functional(*args, **kwargs)
    243     else:
    244       return super(Model, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    458     finally:
    459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py in __init__(self, inputs, outputs, name, trainable)
    113     #     'arguments during initialization. Got an unexpected argument:')
    114     super(Functional, self).__init__(name=name, trainable=trainable)
--> 115     self._init_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
    116 
    117   @trackable.no_automatic_dependency_tracking

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    458     finally:
    459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs)
    189     # Keep track of the network's nodes and layers.
    190     nodes, nodes_by_depth, layers, _ = _map_graph_network(
--> 191         self.inputs, self.outputs)
    192     self._network_nodes = nodes
    193     self._nodes_by_depth = nodes_by_depth

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py in _map_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
    929                              'The following previous layers '
    930                              'were accessed without issue: ' +
--> 931                              str(layers_with_complete_input))
    932         for x in nest.flatten(node.outputs):
    933           computable_tensors.add(id(x))

ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("clarity_8:0", shape=(20, 1), dtype=float32) at layer "clarity_emb". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pay attention to not override the input variables. you overrode `color`, `clarity` and `x` input inside the network

here a possible solution:

```
dense1 = 2**7
dense2 = 2**8
dense3 = 2**9
dropout = 0.8
price_loss = 1
cut_loss = 1
activation= LeakyReLU()
batch_size = 32

#====================================================================
# INPUTS
#====================================================================
carat = Input(shape= (1,), batch_size= batch_size, name= 'carat')
Color = Input(shape= (1,), batch_size= batch_size, name= 'color')
Clarity = Input(shape= (1,), batch_size= batch_size, name= 'clarity')
depth = Input(shape= (1,), batch_size= batch_size, name= 'depth')
table = Input(shape= (1,), batch_size= batch_size, name= 'table')
X = Input(shape= (1,), batch_size= batch_size, name= 'x')
y = Input(shape= (1,), batch_size= batch_size, name= 'y')
z = Input(shape= (1,), batch_size= batch_size, name= 'z')
#====================================================================
# CREATE EMBEDDINGS FOR CATEGORICAL FEATURES "COLOR" AND "CLARITY"
#====================================================================
color = Embedding(input_dim = 7, output_dim = 1, name = 'color_emb')(Color)
clarity = Embedding(input_dim = 8, output_dim = 1, name = 'clarity_emb')(Clarity)
color = Flatten()(color)
clarity = Flatten()(clarity)
#====================================================================
# CONCATENATE FEATURES
#====================================================================
x = Concatenate()([color, clarity, carat, depth, table, X, y, z])
#====================================================================
# DENSE NETWORK
#====================================================================
x = Dense(dense1, activation = activation)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dense(dense2, activation = activation)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dense(dense3, activation = activation)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dropout(dropout)(x)
#====================================================================
# PREDICTIONS
# ====================================================================
cut = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
price = Dense(1)(x)
#====================================================================
# DEFINE THE MODEL
# ====================================================================
model = Model(inputs = [carat, Color, Clarity, depth, table, X, y, z] , 
              outputs = [cut , price])
model.compile('adam', 'mse')
model.summary()
```

here the running notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1akpvuGKHXt6Frrec692zvCMAfRzZbIaM?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Well, like always when we are stuck with some error, the answer lies somewhere in error message. Please note that while you have been able to build the structure of your model overwriting your variables `color`, `clarity` and so on... the variables changed the type. At the beginning you initialize the variables to be `tf.keras.Input` and then you overwrite it with `Embedding` and `Flatten` layers. So when it comes to building your model, you ask to build model with inputs that are no longer `tf.keras.Input` but something else.

The solution is to not overwrite those variables.